# What is the cross browser solution from drag and drop items onto an image?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, cross-browser

We have images which require sections (sections or specific parts of an image) to get droppable.

What is the best cross browser solution?

click events are also required on those same sections in the image.

Comment: Dont know what do u want to set items on image, but  u could try this : https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: This will do it for you https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: To be more specific how to drop onto "sections or specific parts of an image".